I made a function, but got an 'expected identifier when parsing expression, got '='' error
clickdetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
newPart = Instance.new('Part', workspace)
newPart:Destroy()
function createPushBlock():
    newPart = newPart
    newPart.BrickColor = 'Neon orange'
end

clickdetector.MouseClick:Connect(createPushBlock())

I tried to search information in devforum, but i didn't find a useful solution
I expected it to spawn a new part once part is clicked

The : on the end of the line function createPushBlock(): is causing the syntax error- Lua doesn't expect a : there (unlike some other languages like Python).
Simply remove it:
clickdetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
newPart = Instance.new('Part', workspace)
newPart:Destroy()
function createPushBlock()
    newPart = newPart
    newPart.BrickColor = 'Neon orange'
end

clickdetector.MouseClick:Connect(createPushBlock())

